# how to resolve "<class 'NameError'> name 'imaplib' is not defined"

Tags: python, email, imaplib

I want to read emails to fetch attachments.
However i encounter an error "<class 'NameError'> name 'imaplib' is not defined".
I have imaplib installed. What could be a possible reason then?

```
import os
import base64
import pandas as pd
import imaplib
######## i have already tried using "from imaplib import IMAP4"  ##############

EMAIL = 'your email'
PASSWORD = '*****'
EMAIL_SENDER = 'senders email'
XLSX_FILENAME = 'Testing.xlsx'


def download_xlsx_from_email():
    
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com') ###THE ERROR IS SEEMINGLY CAUSED BY THIS LINE####
    mail.login(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
    mail.select('inbox')

    # Search for emails from the specified sender
    _, data = mail.search(None, f'FROM "{EMAIL_SENDER}"')
    email_ids = data[0].split()

    if not email_ids:
        print(f"No emails found from {EMAIL_SENDER}.")
        return None

    # Fetch the latest email
    latest_email_id = email_ids[-1]
    mail.fetch(latest_email_id, '(BODYSTRUCTURE)')

    # Fetch the XLSX attachment
    for part_index in range(1, 10):  # Adjust the range as needed
        _, part_data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, f'(BODY[{part_index}])')
        content_type = part_data[0][1].split(b'Content-Type: ')[1].split(b';')[0].strip()
        if content_type == b'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet':
            _, attachment_data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, f'(BODY[{part_index}])')
            content = attachment_data[0][1]

            with open(XLSX_FILENAME, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(content)
            print(f"Downloaded {XLSX_FILENAME} from email.")
            return XLSX_FILENAME

    print(f"No XLSX attachments found in the email from {EMAIL_SENDER}.")
    return None
```

Comment: check if you're using the same environment where you installed the "imaplib" lib.

Comment: The error was fixed by declaring imaplib as a global variable

Comment: That solution doesn't make sense.